# ExpressionEncgine 1.6.7 Maintain entry order inside a category

Tags: expressionengine

I'm using this code:

```
{exp:weblog:categories weblog="games" style="none" show_empty="no"}
{exp:weblog:entries site="games_site" weblog="games" category="{category_id}" style="linear" disable="member_data|pagination|trackbacks" } 
{title}
{/exp:weblog:entries}
{/exp:weblog:categories}
```

to display all the entries for all categories assigned to a specific weblog.
This works ok, but I would like to maintain the order given to the entry inside each category.
Is there a specific orderby parameter to use?

Comment: I would have thought the orderby parameter would work.  Did you try it? http://ee1docs.com/modules/weblog/parameters.html#par_orderby

Comment: The orderby parameters seem to be all related with the weblog and not with the category itself. I'm getting to the point having to make a SQL query to get the entries within the category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I was confused about what you were asking for.  I think what you want is [the `category_archive` tag](http://ee1docs.com/modules/weblog/category_archive.html).

Something like this:

```
{exp:weblog:category_archive weblog="games" style="none" show_empty="no" style="linear" disable="category_fields"}

{entry_titles}
{title}
{/entry_titles}

{/exp:weblog:category_archive}
```